# How do I write an ASP Array?

Tags: asp-classic

I am new to asp and I want to write the following and place it in an array. How do I start ?

```
a="apple"
b="banan"
number=1
```

If you could also suggest some good reading material I would appreciate it. I already went through w3schools and tutorialpoint

Answer (score 0):

In VBScript, and hence classic ASP, you can do it with such code:

```
Dim myArray, a, b, myNumber
myArray = Array("apple", "banan", 1)
a = myArray(0)
b = myArray(1)
myNumber = myArray(2)
```

Like the .NET `ArrayList` class, the VBScript Array can hold any variable type.